# How to insert id into pivot table by user? laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

I want to make users role system, for that I made three tables: users, roles & role_user pivot table, users & roles are bound by:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
}
```

which has a belongsToMany relationship, and pivot table stored users id & roles id, all fine and I am able to retrieve users role, but into pivot table I insert data manually from phpmyadmin page, my problem is how to insert id into pivot table by users?

Answer (score 0):

:)

I'm not 100% sure, but you can use attach() method on your user model.

Example (be sure you set the $fillable in your models).

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => 'Me!',
    'email' => 'my@email.com',
]);

$role = Role::create([
    'name' => 'First role',
]);
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
$user = User::first();
$user->role()->attach($role);
```

I hope u understood! Good luck. :)